# CSV with un-escaped quotes in data not parsing in PHP's fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv

If I have test.csv such as:

"column1", "column2", "this "is" column3", "column4"\r\n

This breaks into 5 columns using PHP fgetcsv. Is there a way to handle un-escaped  quotes to return 4 columns?

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
  print_r($data);
 }
}
```

Comment: Where does you CSV file come from? You should have a pair of double-quotes to represent an embedded double-quote: `"column2", "this ""is"" column3", "column4"`.

Comment: You could probably use a regexp (preg_replace) that tested if a quote was preceded or succedded by a comma, and "escape" it if none was found.... not a perfect solution, and you'd need to use fgets(), the check and escape, then str_getcsv() rather than the simpler fgetcsv()

Comment: External data source with about 2 million records, so somewhat limited.

Comment: Well there's no magic bullet built into PHP that lets it automagically work with invalid CSV files, you either fix it before parsing it as CSV, or you fix it before giving PHP access to the file

Answer (score 0):

this un-escaped quote is not expect in the CSV format.
so you have to correct the file to have a correct CSV format before to use it with "fgetcsv"